# How to duplicate a Collection in Strapi

Tags: strapi

I would like to duplicate a collection (a db table for me), rename it and use with same fields in Strapi. I need it because I would like to localize the data in them in 12 languages. I don't want to create this collection and fields in it over and over. Is it achievable?

Comment: You can open the API folder and copy the models there, or do some script to do that for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update 02/2023:
As Pierre pointed out - [this feature is now ready](https://strapi.io/features/internationalization).

---

Update: new roadmap link.
No native solution right now. There is one planned for Q3 2020 -  <del>check out the [issue in road-map](https://portal.productboard.com/strapi/1-public-roadmap/c/19-content-internationalization)</del>(dead now). [This is the new roadmap](https://feedback.strapi.io).

---

I think that depending on how many languages you need to support you can do one of the following:

1. As explained [here](https://medium.com/strapi/content-internationalization-with-strapi-507ef5869c15) you can add a suffix to fields. So basically you have a content type with multiple fields for each field like so: `name_en, name_fr` etc. When you retrieve the item you can filter by the suffix.
2. Use a JSON object where key is locale. More info [here](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/1507#issuecomment-419504860).
3. "Bad" option (maybe good for few languages):  Duplicate the content type `api` folder and change files within, thus saving you from editing everything in the admin panel.

Comment: _`"Bad" option (maybe good for few languages):`_ Do you mean "language" as in speech or programming? How is copy-pasting the type folder bad? As well, if doing this, there's likely an additional step needed for Strapi to register the new type folder.

Comment: I meant speech language. I don't fully remember why I wrote that but probably because after you copy paste you would have to keep every change synced across many sources (all copies). So it might work for a specific usecase with few copies(languages) but in general it's not a "good" long term solution if things are changing often.

Comment: FYI, if your goal is to manage content in different languages, the content internationalization feature is now available: https://strapi.io/features/internationalization

Comment: So it seems this answer needs an update, thanks @Pierre